# Minimum replacements in a string to make all 'X' chars to the left of all 'Y chars

Tags: string, algorithm, replace

Hey everyone had this problem in an interview and can't seem to figure out the best way to do it. Any help would be much appreciated.

Problem:

You are given a string S. Each character of the string is either 'W' or 'R'.

- **W** represents a white-colored flower.
- **R** represents a red-colored flower

A string is considered **beautiful** if all the white-colored flowers are on the left of all the red-colored flowers. You can replace any white-colored flower with a red-colored flower and vice versa.

Your task is to find the minimum number of replacements that must be made to make string S beautiful.

sample cases:

1.) input: "RWRW"

output: 2 ("WWRR" or "WWWW" or “RRRR”)

2.) input: "RRRR"

output: 0 ("RRRR")

3.) input: "RWWWRR"

output: 1 ("WWWWRR")

Comment: Please provide some sample cases. Also, can red-colored flowers be to the left of red-colored flowers? Or is the only condition that white-colored flowers must be to the left of a red-colored flower?

Comment: I think you've made a couple of copying errors. _"You can replace any white-colored flower with a white-colored flower"?_ And it's hard to see how the first example can be solved with "WWRR" but not "RRRR", or how the third example went from six flowers to four.

Comment: @Beta Apologies, it's been a long day. Thanks to Abhinav Mathur for fixing the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a dynamic programming problem. Let

```py
dp[i][0] = minimum number of changes if the i-th flower is white
dp[i][1] = minimum number of changes if the i-th flower is white
```

Base state:

```py
dp[0][0] = int(arr[0] != “W”)
dp[0][1] = int(arr[0] != “R”)
```

Now, to calculate the values for `dp[i]`, we look at the cases:

1. If `arr[i] == “R”`

- If `arr[i-1] == “R”`, then `arr[i]` has to be `“R”`.
- If `arr[i-1] == “W”`, then `arr[i]` can be `“R”` or `“W”`.
- `arr[i][1] = min(arr[i-1][0], arr[i-1][1])`
- `arr[i][0] = arr[i-1][0] + 1`

2. If `arr[i] == “W”`

- If `arr[i-1] == “R”`, then `arr[i]` has to be `“R”` (so we’ll have to modify current flower).
- If `arr[i-1] == “W”`, then `arr[i]` can be `“R”` (which needs modification) or `“W”` (no modification needed).
- `arr[i][0] = arr[i-1][0]`
- `arr[i][1] = min(arr[i-1][0], arr[i-1][1]) + 1`

In the end, your answer becomes `min(dp[n-1][0], dp[n-1][1])`

Simple Python implementation:

```py
s = "RWWWRR"
n = len(s)
dp = [[0,0] for i in range(n)]
dp[0][0] = int(s[0] != "W")
dp[0][1] = int(s[0] != "R")
for i in range(1,n):
    if s[i] == "R":
        dp[i][1] = min(dp[i-1])
        dp[i][0] = dp[i-1][0] + 1 
    else:
        dp[i][1] = min(dp[i-1]) + 1 
        dp[i][0] = dp[i-1][0]
    
print(min(dp[n-1]))
```

Comment: Nice approach, but I think this code can be simpler. You don't need the full array, since you only ever use the last-created values, and the initialization can be 0, 0 if you process index 0 in the loop. That makes the very much simpler: https://gist.github.com/paulhankin/9c362dac400baae5b7a743a31200fc78

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved in a single pass through the array keeping O(1) state.

We do this by finding the best place to split the array so that in the solution all the flowers to the left are white and all the flowers to the right are red. That's the same as finding i from 0 to N that minimizes the number of red flowers to the left of i plus the number of white flowers to the right of i, because that's the numbers of flowers we'd have to change to split the array at i.

Suppose the length of the array is N, there's R total red flowers (so N-R red flowers), and let r[i] be the number of red flowers to the left of i, r'[i] the number of red flowers to the right of i, and the same for white flowers with w[i] and w'[i].

We want to find i such that r[i] + w'[i] is minimized (the number of red flowers to the left of i plus the number of white flowers to the right of i -- these are the ones we'd have to change).
But w'[i] + w[i] = (N-R), and r[i] + w[i] = i, so r[i] + w'[i] = r[i] + (N-i)-(R-r[i]) = 2r[i] - i + (N - R).

Thus we need to find i that minimizes 2r[i] - i + (N - R). Since N-R is constant, that's the same as finding i such that 2r[i] - i is minimized. By the time we've processed the whole array, we have the value for R, and can construct the return value.

Here's some python code that uses this method, along with some test cases.

```
def min_changes(A):
    best, besti = 1e12, -1
    r = 0
    for i in range(len(A)+1):
        v = 2 * r - i
        if v < best:
            besti, best = i, v
        if i < len(A):
            r += A[i] == 'R'
    return best + len(A) - r, 'W' * besti + 'R' * (len(A) - besti)

tests = [("RWRW", 2, "RRRR"), ("RRRR", 0, "RRRR"), ("RWWWRR", 1, "WWWWRR")]
for s, n, r in tests:
    gotn, gotr = min_changes(s)
    if gotn != n or gotr != r:
        print("FAILED",)
    print(s, gotn, gotr)
```